# Redshift regular expression match up until pattern match but not include pattern

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

Since Redshift does not support lookahead assertion, I am in need of a way to find a substring pattern match, however, want to include string up to the pattern match without including the pattern itself.

Yes, as an alternative, I could of course use substring(), however, if there is no substring match, I would still like the full string returned.  This approach would require use of sever case statements and would not be suitable.

Using a regular expression would be ideal - for example:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
Match String: jumped
Desired output would be:  The quick brown fox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed string -- and really don't need regular expressions -- just use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part('the quick brown fox jumps', 'jump', 1)
```